# Update text inside a div

Tags: jquery

How do I update `<h2>` text inside a particular div?

```
<div id="outerwrapper">
  <div id="wrapper>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>

$('#wrapper').text("new text");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#wrapper').find('h2').text("new text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerwrapper">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#wrapper').find('h2').text("new text");
```

Use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find child element of a `wrapper`:

```
$('#wrapper').find("h2").text("new text");
```

Or use [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$('#wrapper h2').text("new text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#wrapper h2').html("new text");
```

And you've missed a quotation here: `<div id="wrapper>`

Code should be like this:

```
<div id="outerwrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h2></h2>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your javascript code must be `$('#wrapper h2').text("new text");` you only have to add the required tag after the ID.

Instead of
`$('#wrapper').text("new text");`

By the way that code line should be inside

```
<script></script>
```

And inside a function. E.g.

```
(function($){
     //your code here
 })
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(){
     //your code here
 })
```